# Modeling States in Alloy: Syntax for all relations identical except the following

Tags: alloy

While modeling states, I find myself often in the same situation.

The State signature has some (larger) number of relations within it. Within a particular transition, I effectively want to say something like: "Everything in the pre-state is the same as the post-state, *except* the following"

```
pred SampleTransition (s, s': State, f: Foo) {
    s = s' but
        s'.foos = s.foos - f
}
```

Does anything like this exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Alloy book](http://softwareabstractions.org/) discusses various options -- look up "frame conditions" in the index.

People often define an unchanged predicate in the event paradigm which makes the spec more readable:

```
pred Event.unchanged (field: univ -> Time) {
    field.(this.pre) = field.(this.post)
    }
```

You can also define a predicate like this

```
pred modifies (es: set Event, field: univ -> Time) {
    all e: Event - es | field.(e.pre) = field.(e.post)
    }
```

and use it in Reiter-style frame conditions like this (from book's hotel locking example):

```
sig Room {
    key: Key one -> Time,
    prev:  Key lone -> Time,
    occ: Guest -> Time
    }
    {
    Checkin.modifies [prev]
    (Checkin + Checkout).modifies [occ]
    RecodeEnter.modifies [key]
    }
```

At one point we experimented with a [meta capability](http://alloytools.org/quickguide/meta.html) that allowed you to define a predicate like this

```
pred Event.modifies (fs: set field$) {
    all f: field$ - fs | f.value.(this.pre) = f.value.(this.post)
    }
```

but there wasn't much enthusiasm for it.

Comment: Thank you for the examples and book references -- really enjoying the book so far.